# Camera_info for a camera publishing already rectified images

Tags: ros, calibration, driver, camera, camera-info

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a camera which gives me images which are already rectified. I'm writing the ROS driver  for it and I'm wondering what I should do with the camera_info message. Should I :

- Calibrate the camera and publish the intrinsic parameters in the camera_info message
- Calibrate the camera and publish the projection matrix but set the distortion parameters to 0
- Not calibration and set all the camera_info parameters to 0

For the record, I do not have access to the prerectified image, only the final result.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233464/camera_info-for-a-camera-publishing-already-rectified-images/) by [JustinBlack02](https://answers.ros.org/users/26403/justinblack02/) on ROS Answers with karma: 131 on 2016-05-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

- Setting the first element of the intrinsic matrix, `K[0]`,  to `0.0` should be accepted by the various image pipeline components as a "raw" or uncalibrated image. That would probably work fine for your device.
- Alternatively, you could run the ROS calibration tool and publish its calibration. I would expect that to work OK with your already-calibrated images, although you should experiment to confirm that guess. **Edit**: *experiment revealed unsatisfactory results.*

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2016-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JustinBlack02](https://answers.ros.org/users/26403/justinblack02/) on 2016-05-05**:
Thanks!

For the second part of your answer, I did try but after the second rectification everything looks a lot worse .

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-05-05**:
Good to know, thanks for following up.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-05-05**:
It's not customary to close a question just because it has an acceptable answer. I'll re-open it.